# Attach file using COM class - olMailItem in PHP

Tags: php, outlook, sendmail, email-attachments

I´d like to send an email using the COM class in PHP.
It worked well until I tried to add attachments, whitch is the most important part of what I need to do.

I´d appreciate your help.

Here is the code I´ve done. 
Without the "$oMsg->attachments->Add("file path", "file name");" line it worked perfectly.

```
<?php
    $standard_email = "myemail@...";
    $UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/";

    //

    $UPLOAD_FILE = $UPLOAD_PATH.$_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $UPLOAD_FILE);
    echo $UPLOAD_FILE;


    if (!defined("olMailItem")) {
        define("olMailItem",0);
    }
    $oApp  = new COM("Outlook.Application") or die('error');
    $oMsg = $oApp->CreateItem(olMailItem);
    $oMsg->Recipients->Add($standard_email);
    $oMsg->Subject="Testing";
    $oMsg->Body="Test";

    //Add attachement - here I get an error
    $oMsg->attachments->Add("file path", "file name");


    $oMsg->Save();
    $oMsg->Send();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are wrong. `Attachments.Add` takes 4 parameters, 1 of them is required, the other 3 are optional: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553(v=office.15).aspx

In your case you only need the first parameter, which is the fully qualified file name (path plus file name).

Answer (score -1):

Just use :

```
$oMsg->attachments->Add("file path");
```